# How to mark item as selected according to query string parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

Query string parameter _layout may contain values from 0 to 9
and may also missing.

If query string parameter is not present, item 0 must marked as selected.
Bootstrap 3 dropdown menu item should marked as selected according to its value.
I tried code below but item is not marked probably since onload event is not supported in span element.

How to fix ?

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li>
     <a onclick="LaadiVorm(0)">
       <span onload="if(getParameterByName('_layout')=0)  $(this).css('glyphicon glyphicon-ok')" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        Vorm  0
     </a>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a onclick="LaadiVorm(1)">
        <span onload="if(getParameterByName('_layout')=1)  $(this).css('glyphicon glyphicon-ok')" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        Vorm  1
     </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

getParameterByName is from  [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) :

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

jquery, bootstrap 3, ASP.NET MVC4 are used.

Also using this style does not keep empty space before unselectedted item.
Result is:

```
v Vorm 0
Vorm 1
```

How to aling all captions so that result is

```
v Vorm 0
  Vorm 1
```

Using glyphicons are not required, `v` character in some font or something other  understandable can used to mark current item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to explain you everithing.

#### ISSUES

- `onload` has no sense on SPANs (it is used on body or img).
- `$(selector).css(rules)` is used to set CSS rules, not classes.
- you can compare values with a double equals sign (i.e. `a == b`).

#### SOLUTIONS

I think you should remove the `onload` and add this Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var layoutParam = getParameterByName('_layout');
  $('.dropdown-menu li span').get(layoutParam).addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok');
});
```

For your alignment issue, you should add left padding with CSS. Maybe the [`:not()` pseudo-selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp) could be useful:

```
.dropdown-menu li span:not(.glyphicon.glyphicon-ok){
    padding-left: 30px; //or a different dimension :)
}
```

#### A LITTLE TIP

I suggest you to add an `id` to your `<ul>` and use it in your selectors.

Comment: `layout` is undefined. Glyphicon must placed into separate span or i element. This code changes also li element caption font

Comment: `layout` was a typo... I edited my answer in order to include an additional `<span>`